# Show multiple items in selectbox after submit

Tags: php

To get the chosen value in a select box after submit.
I use:

```
<option value="<?=$row["status"]?>" <?=($row["status"]==$status) ? 'selected' : ''?> >
```

How do I get multiple items when using an array in PHP?

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-top:5px">Status</div>
                    <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-top:5px">
                        <select name="status[]" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple>
                            <?php
                            $sel = "
                                SELECT DISTINCT
                                    t.status,
                                    s.*
                                FROM tickets t
                                LEFT JOIN statussen s
                                ON t.status = s.stid
                                GROUP BY s.stid
                                ";
                            $selres = mysqli_query( $link, $sel );
                            while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $selres ) ):
                                ?>
                            <option value="<?=$row["status"]?>" <?=($row["status"]==$status) ? 'selected' : ''?> >
                                <?=$row["status_omschr"]?>
                            </option>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Comment: can we know what is being wrong? is only one item being shown as selected as compared to multiple?

Comment: Yes, by choosing one item, the value is shown, but by multiple items, nothing is shown...

Comment: Please submit complete drop-down with code you are using.

Comment: @JackKral: thanks for editing the question. I have submitted the answer. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Add before your loop:

   ```
   $selectedItems = [];
   if(isset($_POST['status'])) {
     $selectedItems = $_POST['status'];
   }
   ```
2. Change within the loop:

   ```
   <option value="<?=$row["status"]?>" <?=(in_array($row["status"], $_POST['status'])) ? 'selected' : ''?> >
     <?=$row["status_omschr"]?>
   </option>
   ```

Comment: Okay, that was too fast. If you don't perform the request per POST, there is no such array. I'll add something to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with using [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function in condition like below.

```
 <option value="<?=$row["status"]?>" <?php if(isset($_POST['status']) and !empty($_POST['status'])){ ?> <?=(in_array($row["status"], $_POST['status'])) ? 'selected' : ''?> <?php }?>  >
  <?=$row["status_omschr"]?>
</option>
```